# Script: How to copy and reapply conditional formatting rules to a range on edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, the range of cells that conditional formatting applies to can change when you paste in new values. I'm looking for a script that will copy the conditional formatting present in the sheet and reapply it to new cells as people paste in data.

I don't actually do much scripting, but I steal other people's scripts and Frankenstein them together until they're vaguely functional. Here's what I've stolen so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  range.clearFormat();
  //clears formatting just on data that is pasted into the sheet

  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];
  for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
    var booleanCondition = rules[r].getBooleanCondition();
    if(booleanCondition != null) {
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
      .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackground())
      .setRanges([sheet.getRange("A:A"),sheet.getRange("C:C")])
      .build();
      newRules.push(rule);
      sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem, of course, is that I'm getting ALL of the conditional formatting rules for that sheet and applying them all to two columns (A:A and C:C). These rules are applied regardless of what columns they used to apply to.

Can someone suggest a way to copy the pre-existing Conditional Formatting rules and reapply them to the columns I copied them from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setRanges() function [1] is where you need to set up the range to which you want the formatting to be applied. In this case, I used the edited range which you're getting from the event object of the onEdit trigger [2]:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  range.clearFormat();
  //clears formatting just on data that is pasted into the sheet

  //Get all Sheet rules and iterate through them
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];
  newRules = newRules.concat(rules);

  for(var r = 0; r < rules.length; r++) {
    var rule = rules[r];
    //Get condition for each rule
    var booleanCondition = rule.getBooleanCondition();

    //Get the ranges to which each rule applies and iterate through
    var ranges = rule.getRanges();
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      var ruleColumn = ranges[i].getColumn();  

      //If condition isn't null and edited column is the same as the one in the range, add rule
      if((ruleColumn == column) && (booleanCondition != null)) {
        var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues())
        .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackground())
        .setRanges([range])
        .build();
        newRules.push(newRule);
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
}
```

I also put this line outside the for loop because inserting all the formatting rules in the sheet is needed only once:

```
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setRanges(Range)

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thank you, Andres!

Unfortunately, I'm still running into the same issue. Regardless of what ranges I specify with the setRanges() function, the conditional formatting rules for the entire sheet get applied to that range. I'm looking for a solution that takes the conditional format rules from each column and reapplies them to the same column when data is added.

Do you have any insight into... say, how to selectively retrieve conditional format rules by column and reapply them by column?

Comment: I just edited the answer using [getRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule#getRanges()) function for each rule and setting the rule to the edited cell based on that. If you need to tweak the code check the documentation I provided you. If it helped you please consider accepting the answer as correct.

Comment: It definitely helped. The conditional formatting is now being applied to each column correctly, but it creates a new iteration of each rule, which the script gets and reapplies to the next range when there is an edit. The iterations of the same rule grow exponentially every time the script is activated. Is there a way to pull the conditional formatting only from specified cells like "A2:Z2"? That would be a perfect work around.

Thanks again!

Comment: I can't answer this in a comment, if you want ask a new question.

Comment: Ah, thanks for helping me stay compliant with SO's site rules. I marked your answer as correct and [posted a separate question about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987594/script-how-to-retrieve-conditional-formatting-rules-from-specified-cells-and-se) You've been immensely helpful in compiling this script and helping me understand the language more effectively. I appreciate it!

Comment: No worries! glad I could help.