# Change range in ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script

**Goal**: Change range (sheetname, not the a1Notation) inside a ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder.copy()

**Error:** Conditional format rule cannot reference a different sheet.

I am trying to use the copy method thats is (not so) [explained](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#copy()). With the copy i know i have al the arguments for the new conditional formatting i need. Only thing i need to change is the sheetname. Add ranges is working fine, but change/clear the ranges i can't seem to figure out. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814849/script-how-to-copy-and-reapply-conditional-formatting-rules-to-a-range-on-edit), but i want it to make more generic. This example is fine if you know the conditions to work with.

In the docs there is also a .build() is that a option i need in implement?

**MainFunction:**

```
function copyFormattingToTargets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //const input = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Copy formatting from:").getResponseText();
  const input = 'Data';
  const targets = ['Log','Test'];
  const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName(input);
  const inputRules = templateSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  const rules = convertRules(inputRules,targets);

  targets.forEach(target => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target);
    target.clearConditionalFormatRules();
    target.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  })
  
}
```

**ConvertFunction:**

```
function convertRules(rules,sheetnames){
  const output = [];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  sheetnames.forEach(sh => {
    rules.forEach(rule => {
      const copy = rule.copy();
      const newRanges = [];
      const oldRanges = copy.getRanges();
      oldRanges.forEach(range => {
        const buildRange = ss.getSheetByName(sh).getRange(range.getA1Notation());
        newRanges.push(buildRange);
      });
      copy.setRanges(newRanges);
      output.push(copy);
    });
  });
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder.copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#copy), it will return a [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) type data.

You need to use [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder.build()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#build()) to generate a [ConditionalFormatRule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule) based on your modified range which can be used to set sheet's conditional format rules using [Sheet.setConditionalFormatRules()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setconditionalformatrulesrules)

### Example Code: (Copy Conditional Formatting Rules from Sheet1 to Sheet2 and change its range by adding column offset of 2)

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var targetSh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var rules = sourceSh.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];

  rules.forEach((rule, index) => {
    Logger.log("****rule****");
    var ruleBuilder = rule.copy();
    var ranges = ruleBuilder.getRanges();

    ranges.forEach(range => {
      Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
    })

    //Select C1:C1000 as new range
    var newRange = targetSh.getRange(1,index + 3,1000,1); 
    ruleBuilder.setRanges([newRange]);

    Logger.log("****new range****");
    var ranges = ruleBuilder.getRanges();

    ranges.forEach(range => {
      Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
    })
    
    Logger.log("****build modified rule****");
    var newRule = ruleBuilder.build();
    newRules.push(newRule);

  });

  targetSh.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
}
```

### OUTPUT:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

### Your Code:

```
function convertRules(rules,sheetnames){
  const output = [];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  sheetnames.forEach(sh => {
    rules.forEach(rule => {
      const copy = rule.copy();
      const newRanges = [];
      const oldRanges = copy.getRanges();
      oldRanges.forEach(range => {
        const buildRange = ss.getSheetByName(sh).getRange(range.getA1Notation());
        newRanges.push(buildRange);
      });
      copy.setRanges(newRanges);
      copy.build(); // Build conditional format rules based on modified range
      output.push(copy);
    });
  });
  return output;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I knew it had to do something with .build() but could not wrap my head around it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong because I don't use format rules much.  But it seems to me that rules is an array of individual rule items. And the convertRules() returns that array so:

Perhaps this code might be something like this:

```
 targets.forEach((target,i) => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(target);
    target.clearConditionalFormatRules();
    target.setConditionalFormatRules(rules[i]);
  })
```

I'm not really sure about this so if I'm wrong then I'll be glad  to delete the answer.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts and effort. But you can pass in a array at once. The problem is in the covert part. I have a copy, but the copy has the range (including the sheet reference) from the input sheet. That part i need to change somehow.. (i would leave your awnser so other users can read this as informational purpose)